# Find a suitable integrating factor for $\,y'=1+x+y+xy,\;y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{align}
y\hspace{0.25ex}'&=1+x+y+xy, &y(0)&=0
\end{align}

I'm confused as to how I get started with this one.  Do I need to separate the variables first and then integrate?

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about Separation of Variables since the RHS is $(1+x)(1+y)$. Now you can write $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dy}{1+y} = \int (1+x) dx$.

Comment: @Moo that's what I figured, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Moo I got $y=e^{x(1+\frac{x}{2})}e^c-1$ but I guess since $e^c-1$ is just a number I could just make that $C$ - giving me $y=e^{x(1+\frac{x}{2})}C$

Comment: @Moo thanks so much for your help!

Comment: However, do not forget that you have an IC to find $C$. Oops, sorry - no on $e^c -1$ just being another constant. At $x = 0$, $y = 0 \implies C = 1$

Comment: Thanks, I almost forgot about the initial condition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question specifically asked for an integrating factor, then you need to write it as $$y'-(1+x)y=1+x$$ so the integrating factor is $$e^{-\int 1+xdx}=e^{-x-\frac{x^2}2}$$